# How can I combine files with matching ending characters?

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system, glob

I have excel files named like "name1 01.01.2018.xlsx", "name1 01.01.2018.xlsx", "name2 12.23.2019.xlsx", and so on. I want to join all files with matching dates (last 10 characters).

I can join all of them by doing:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas

os.chdir('filepath')
files = [pd.read_excel(p, skipfooter=1) for p in glob.glob("*.xlsx")]
df = files[0].drop(files[0].tail(0).index).append([files[i].drop(files[i].tail(0).index) for i in range(1,len(files))])
```

How can I join only when the last characters match? I don't have a list of options for the last 10 characters, I want it to update automatically.

Comment: What do you mean with `join`? You want to append them on top of each other? Or next to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off, we need to reformat your code a bit. While the line to join the Dataframes is correct, it's very difficult to read and can be accomplished more efficiently:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('filepath')
files = [pd.read_excel(p, skipfooter=1) for p in glob.glob("*.xlsx")]

# drop the tail of all files
files = [f.drop(f.tail(0).index) for f in files]

# join all files
df = files[0].append(files[1:])
```

Then, we need to update it a bit so that you can check the filename of the files you loaded, and have some way to tie them back to the Dataframe you created.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('filepath')

# store last 10 characters of original filename
files = [(p[-10:], pd.read_excel(p, skipfooter=1)) for p in glob.glob("*.xlsx")]

# drop the tail of all files
files = [(p, f.drop(f.tail(0).index)) for p, f in files]

# group files by last 10 characters of filename
files = {p: [g for n, g in files if n == p] for p in set(p for p, f in files)}

# join all files with same last 10 characters
for key, value in files.items():
    files[key] = value[0].append(value[1:])
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and help cleaning the code. I tried it with two files on a folder, "name1 06.02.2019.xlsx" and "name2 06.02.2019.xlsx", files.keys() returned dict_keys(['.2019.xlsx'])

Comment: Is it because of the dot?

Comment: Nevermind, just changing 10 for 15 solves the problem(".xlsx" also counts). Thank you!

Comment: @LuanVieira Check out line 8: that is what determines the key. It looks like you actually need the last 15 characters of the filename, not the last 10 like you said - remember, the extension is part of the filename!

Comment: Actually, it only works when all files end with the same last 15 characters. Otherwise I get IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-1ab6dd853616> in <module>
     16 # join all files with same last 10 characters
     17 for key, value in files.items():
---> 18     files[key] = value[0].append(value[1:])

Comment: @LuanVieira it looks like that's a separate issue, you should post another question. Also, please don't post questions or changes in the comments, it should go in the question itself. Comments are intended for clarification only and are often deleted once they have served their purpose.

Comment: Sorry about that. The issue was that I had files for which there was only one value. So value[1:] wouldn't apply. I solved it with if and else.